# C++ data structures and CUDA

Tags: c++, data-structures, cuda

i have a structure which can be

```
  struct type1{ double a,b,c;}
```

or it can be

```
  struct type2{ double a,b,c,d,e;}
```

in my host function of cuda code i have someting like

```
  void compute(){
      // some code
      // data on devices (up to 10) 
      type *xxx[10];   // this is where i want either type1 or type2 structures
                       // the "type" is not known at compile time but i want to 
                       // determine at runtime based on some input variable. this 
                       // part is not real code rather this is what i want to achive.

      int DevUsed;    // some code to give value to int DevUsed

      for(int idev=0;idev<DevUsed;idev++){

           // set cuda device

          if ( cudaMalloc(&xxx[iDev], sizeof(type)) != cudaSuccess )
            // print error message;
          cudaMemcpy(xxx[iDev], pIF1, sizeof(type), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

          function2<<<grid, block>>>(xxx[iDev]);  // where function2 is the kernel
       }
   }
```

My question is what is a way to select between type1 and type2 data struct with generic code like "type *xxx[10];"

Comment: try using `typeid` if it's runtime only

Comment: Templates? http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: You are trying to declare an `array` of `10` pointers to data of a `type` not known at compile-time? I'm not sure you could do that with templates, since template functions, structs or classes require instantiations at compile-time. Probably the best you can do is to declare an array of pointers to `void`? But I have the feeling that you should know all the types at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

C++ template is designed for this situation.

```
template <class T>
void compute(){
  // some code
  // data on devices (up to 10) 
  T xxx[10];   // this is where i want either type1 or type2 structures
                   // the "type" is not known at compile time but i want to 
                   // determine at runtime based on some input variable. this 
                   // part is not real code rather this is what i want to achive.

  int DevUsed;    // some code to give value to int DevUsed

  for(int idev=0;idev<DevUsed;idev++){

       // set cuda device

      if ( cudaMalloc(&xxx[iDev], sizeof(T)) != cudaSuccess )
        // print error message;
      cudaMemcpy(xxx[iDev], pIF1, sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

      function2<<<grid, block>>>(xxx[iDev]);  // where function2 is the kernel
   }
}
```

Please note that you will also need a kernel template for these two types like

```
template <class T>
__global__ void function2(T x)
{
    //....
}
```

Comment: But with templates I think you should explicitly instantiate the functions at compile time. How is it possible when the user claims to know the type `T` only at runtime?

Comment: Guess he should implement the code for both types and select the one at runtime...